# Underscore's findWhere and MongoDB object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mongodb, underscore.js

I use MongoDB and I want to use Underscore.js in my Angular app.
I have a model "Email" with the fields: "subject", "body" and "id".

This Email object looks like this in the browser console:

```
$$hashKey   
    "005"

_id     
    Object { $oid="5478774a6a61734d8a000000"}

body        
    "Here is the sample conte...le ble ble. Nice email."

subject     
    "This is first template"
```

This is the controller code in Angular:

```
$scope.viewEmail = function(emailId) {

    var email = _.findWhere(emailData.data.emails, { _id: emailId });

    console.log(email);
};
```

So, I just want to find an email with the specific `id` - the `id` I want to get is saved in a local variable `emailId`.

I should do something like that: `_id.$oid: emailId` but it causes a syntax error in the javascript console: "missing : after property id".

Comment: `findWhere` is not adapted if you have to dig an object in an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:
`_.find(list, predicate, [context])`

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bqegdy2t/

```
var emailData = {
    data: {
        emails: [
            { _id: { $oid: "someId" }, body: "Hello Every Body1" },
            { _id: { $oid: "someOtherId" }, body: "Hello Every Body2" },
        ]
    }
};

var emailId = "someId";
var email = _.find(emailData.data.emails, function(email) { 
                return email._id.$oid === emailId;
            });

console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

the difficulty lies in the mongo objectid format that is an unusual JSON object containing string.

try `_id: emailId` versus `_id.$oid: emailId`

another option: dot notation often needs quotes around it `"_id.$oid" : emailId` especially those with dollar signs